# Clausula sql where para casos en que los valores de columna deben cumplir de forma combinada la condición

Tags: sql, mysqli

```
id | expediente_id | area_id
1            5           1
2            5           3
3            6           1
4            7           5
5            7           8
```

Hola tengo la una tabla N a N. Quería saber como puedo obtener los expediente_id que cumplen con todas las area_id en forma combinada. Es decir, si pido los expedientes donde este el área 1, solo quiero que me traiga los expedientes que tengan solo el área 1, en este caso el expediente 6. Si coloco los ids de área 1 y 3 me tiene que traer solo el expediente 5 y no el 6. Si pido expedientes donde esten las áreas (1, 5, 8) no me tendría que traer ningún expediente porque esa combinación no se cumple en un mismo expediente.

Pasando en limpio

- area_id = 1, Esperado expediente_id = 6
- area_id = (1,3), Esperado expediente_id = 5
- area_id = (1,5,8), Esperado expediente_id = vacío

Necesitaría saber como podría escribir la condición en el where para obtener estos resultados. Gracias

Comment: La pregunta es confusa. Cuando `area_id` sea igual a `1` habrá `expediente_id` igual a `5` y `6`, pero dices que en ese caso esperas solamente el `6`¿? No sé. Y me da la impresión que algo anda mal o en tu modelo de datos o en tu lógica. Quizá si das más detalles podemos ayudarte mejor. Para entender mejor, quizá sea bueno que muestres un ejemplo con datos de lo que esperas, indicando exactamente las columnas que vas a necesitar en los resultados.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Intentaste algo?

Comment: @A.Cedano quiere solo obtener los expedientes que cumplan con todas las condiciones, no por fila, si no por tabla... y para todos los casos.. por eso el 1 solo le trae el 6, porque el 1,3 no esta en el 6...

Comment: @gbianchi ohhh ok. Me pregunto por qué se habrá llegado a un requerimiento tan complicado en este caso ... ¿?

Comment: Esto lo estás utilizando sólo con SQL o utilizas otro lenguaje para manejarlo como PHP?

Comment: Podrías intentarlo con `WHERE IN`, algo así por ejemplo: `SELECT expediente_id FROM laTabla WHERE id_area IN (n1,n2,n3,n9999) GROUP BY expediente_id` donde `n...` es cada valor a usar como criterio.

Comment: Hola! muchas gracias por responder. Es así como dice @gbianchi. Hoy lo tengo resuelto a nivel de código con PHP pero quería saber si lo podía optimizar directamente desde la consulta SQL. Intenté con el where in pero si colocas alguna area_id que coincida el resto no importa porque dentro del IN trabaja con "OR"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agrupando `area_id` por expediente y comparando la cadena resultante.

```
SELECT expediente_id
  FROM tabla
  GROUP BY expediente_id
  HAVING group_concat(area_id ORDER BY area_id) = concat_ws(',', 1, 3)
```

Cuidando que los `area_id` que mandes a la función `concat_ws()` esten ordenados ascendentemente.

Si falta o sobra algún `area__id` no cumplirá la condición.

Comment: Hola! Muchas Gracias me funciona bien de esta forma. Me voy a poner a investigar sobre concat porque no lo concía a nivel SQL así puedo aprender